# How to put a big UIView on above every window of each app and SpringBoard in iOS on jailbroken device?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak, tweak

I want to put a `UIView` at the top most of the screen to catch the touch events, I mean the `UIView` is not in my app, but also in other apps even SpringBoard.Can anyone give a help?Thank you!

Comment: [Mobile Substrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate)

Comment: Yes, I know MobileSubstrate, but I don't know the specific way, would you tell me how to do it?Thank you.